# Algorithm to determine if a range contains a case-insensitive search phrase?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, range, case-insensitive

Let's say you have thousands of files organized in the following way: First you sort them by their filename (case sensitive, so that upper case files come before lower case), then you grouped them into folders that contain the name of the first and the last file in that folder. E.g., the folders may look like:

```
Abel -> Cain
Camel -> Sloth
Stork -> basket
basking -> sleuth
tiger -> zebra
```

Now, given a *case-insensitive* search string `s`, determine which folders that can contain a file that matches `s`. You cannot and do not have to look inside a folder - the file does not actually have to exist.

Some examples:

```
("Abel", "Cain")    matches s = "blue",   since it contains "Blue"
("Stork", "basket") matches s = "arctic", since it contains "arctic"
("FA", "Fb")        matches s = "foo",    since it contains "FOo"
("Fa", "Fb") does NOT match s = "foo"
```

Formally: Given a closed range `[a,b]` and a lower case string `s`, determine if there's any string `c` in `[a,b]` such that `lower(c) = s`.

My first hunch was to do a case-insensitive search against the bounds of the range. But it can be easily seen from the last example that this is not correct.

A bruce-force solution is to generate all potential file names. For example, the input string `"abc"` would produce the candidates `"ABC", "ABc", "AbC", "Abc", "aBC", "aBc", "abC", "abc"`. Then you just test each against the bounds. An example of this brute-force solution will follow below. This is `O(2^n)` though.

**My question is if there's an algorithm for this that is both fast and correct?**

---

Brute-force solution in Clojure:

```
(defn range-contains 
  [first last string]
  (and (<= (compare first string) 0)
       (>= (compare last string) 0)))

(defn generate-cases
  "Generates all lowercase/uppercase combinations of a word"
  [string]
  (if (empty? string)
    [nil]
    (for [head [(java.lang.Character/toUpperCase (first string))
                (java.lang.Character/toLowerCase (first string))]
          tail (generate-cases (rest string))]
      (cons head tail))))

(defn range-contains-insensitive 
  [first last string]
  (let [f (fn [acc candidate] (or acc (range-contains first last (apply str candidate))))]
    (reduce f false (generate-cases string))))

(fact "Range overlapping case insensitive"
  (range-contains-insensitive "A" "Z" "g") => true
  (range-contains-insensitive "FA" "Fa" "foo") => true
  (range-contains-insensitive "b" "z" "a") => false
  (range-contains-insensitive "B" "z" "a") => true)
```

Comment: if we take numbers a range can be like this `1000-1999`, the same thing in strings is a regular expression `1[0-9][0-9][0-9]` .. in your problem you can consider using `.` as anything after converting the common prefix literals from `a` or `A` to `[aA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of creating all the upper-lower case combinations, this can be solved by checking upper, then lower for each character separately, which changes 2^N into 2N.

The idea is the following:

- keep "lowdone" and "highdone" flags, which indicate whether s can *definitely* come after the low limit while still potentially coming before the high limit, and vice versa
- go character by character through the string
- check if the uppercase version of the current letter can come after the corresponding low limit letter while at the same time coming before the high limit letter, then check the same for the lowercase version of the letter, if neither letter satisfies **both** conditions, return false (don't check low limit if "lowdone" is true, don't check high limit if "highdone" is true - when comparing ABC and ACA, once we are past the second letter, we don't care about the third letter)
- if a case satisfies both conditions, check if it comes **strictly** after the low limit letter or the low limit is too short to have a corresponding letter, if so, lowdone = true
- analogous for highdone = true

Does this sound good? Code in C# (could probably be written more concisely):

```
        public Bracket(string l, string u)
        {
            Low = l;
            High = u;
        }

        public bool IsMatch(string s)
        {
            string su = s.ToUpper();
            string sl = s.ToLower();

            bool lowdone = false;
            bool highdone = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                char[] c = new char[]{su[i], sl[i]};

                bool possible = false;
                bool ld = lowdone;
                bool hd = highdone;
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    if ((lowdone || i >= Low.Length || c[j] >= Low[i]) && (highdone || i >= High.Length || c[j] <= High[i]))
                    {
                        if (i >= Low.Length || c[j] > Low[i])
                            ld = true;

                        if (i >= High.Length || c[j] < High[i])
                            hd = true;

                        possible = true;
                    }
                }
                lowdone = ld;
                highdone = hd;

                if (!possible)
                    return false;
            }

            if (!lowdone && Low.Length > s.Length)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake when porting this solution, there's an error. It returns true for the search string "ad" and the range [Ae, Oa], but "AD" and "Ad" are outside the range to the left, and "aD" and "ad" are outside the range to the right.

Comment: I think this is because cannot use the uppercase "A" to say that it's inside one range and the lowercase "a" to say it's inside the other range - for the actual filename it can't be both uppercase and lowercase. :)

Comment: There was a bug in the code, I fixed it. The problem was that once I change "highdone" due to an uppercase A, it is used in the second iteration of the loop for the lowercase a which should fail (it is > "O") but succeeds due to highdone already being true, then it sets "lowdone" to true, and the second letter was never even checked (the bug also happens for just the string "a"). The flags are only supposed to be used for the *following* letters, not for the other casing of the same letter.

Comment: I think I have another bug. Give me a sec. :)

Comment: I updated the code, and for my test cases it now works perfectly! Amazed that you were able to solve it so quickly, as I found this problem a number of subtle problems I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Check the updated-again code. The bug that was still remaining was that while I was handling the case of the search string being longer than the limits, I forgot the case of it being shorter. So [Ae, Oa] was still failing with "a". I think it should finally work now.

Comment: You are right. But for *my* use case the previous version was actually better, because it treats the search string as a *prefix*. I.e., "a" is interpreted as "a*" and thus matches a range [abc, foo]. I had forgotten to add that as a condition to the problem. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of full disclosure, I guess I should also add the algorithm I came up with (Java, uses Guava):

```
public static boolean inRange(String search, String first, String last) {
    int len = search.length();
    if (len == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    char low = Strings.padEnd(first, len, (char) 0).charAt(0);
    char high = Strings.padEnd(last, len, (char) 0).charAt(0);

    char capital = Character.toLowerCase(search.charAt(0));
    char small = Character.toUpperCase(search.charAt(0));

    if (low == high) {
        if (capital == low || small == low) {
            // All letters equal - remove first letter and restart
            return inRange(search.substring(1), first.substring(1), last.substring(1));
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (containsAny(Ranges.open(low, high), capital, small)) {
        return true; // Definitely inside
    }

    if (!containsAny(Ranges.closed(low, high), capital, small)) {
        return false; // Definitely outside
    }

    // Edge case - we are on a bound and the bounds are different
    if (capital == low || small == low) {
        return Ranges.atLeast(first.substring(1)).contains(search.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    else {
        return Ranges.lessThan(last.substring(1)).contains(search.substring(1).toUpperCase());
    }
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean containsAny(Range<T> range, T value1, T value2) {
    return range.contains(value1) || range.contains(value2);
}
```